# What is the field of fractions of this integral domain?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, field-theory

Let $X$ be an affine variety, i.e. an irriducible closed subset of $A_K^n$, with $K$ be an algebraically closed field. Let $P$ be a point of $X$. Then $O_{X,P}$ is defined to be the set of the pair $(U,f)$ where $U$ is an open subset of $X$ containing $P$ and $f$ is a regular function on $U$, modulo the equivalence relation $(U,f)\sim (V,g) $ if $f_{|U\cap V}=g_{|U\cap V}.$

Let $K(X)$ be the set of the pair $(U,f)$ where $U$ is a non-empty open subset of $X$ and $f$ is a regular funcion on $U$, modulo the equivalence relation $(U,f)\sim (V,g) $ if $f_{|U\cap V}=g_{|U\cap V}.$ Note that since $X$ is irreducible, the intersection of two non empty open subset of $X$ is a non empty open subset of $X$. Then $K(X)$ is a field, with operations $[(U,f)]+[(V,g)]=[(U\cap V, f+g)]$ and $[(U,f)]*[(V,g)]=[(U\cap V, f*g)]$.

Then $O_{X,P}$ is a ring with the same above operations, and $$[(U,f)]\in O_{X,P}\mapsto [(U,f)]\in K(X)$$ is an injective ring homomorphism.

My book says that the field of fractions of $O_{X,P}$ is (isomorphic to) $K(X)$. Why? Can you let see this to me?

Question n°2) If $R$ is an integral domain and $S$ is a multiplicatively closed subset of $R$, then R embedds in $S^{-1}R$, and the field of fractions of $R$ is isomorphic to the field of fractions of $S^{-1}R$, right?

Answer (score 0):

Try to get an intuitive understanding with varieties over the complex numbers.  Here $K(X)$ consists of rational functions, that is ratio of polynomials, which are defined in an open set where the denominator is non-zero. (That open set being unspecified and varies with each function).

Now the local ring $O_{X,P}$ represents rational functions that consists of rational functions with an extra requirement that they be defined at $P$. SO this will be a ring sandwiched between the affine co-ordinate ring $K[X]$ and its fraction field. All these sandwiched rings are integral domains and have the same fraction field is easy to verify.

Comment: @P Vanchinathan  I know that $O_{X,P}$ is isomorphic to the localized $A(X)_{m_P}$ where $m_P$ is the maximal ideal in $A(X)$ consisting of the polynomial functions of $X$ that vanish in $P$. Now, if my second question is right, i have that for each $P$, the field of fractions of $A(X)$ is isomoprhic to the field of fractions of $A(X)_{m_P}$ and so all the $A(X)_{m_P}$ and all the $O_{X,P}$ have the same field of fractions.

Comment: My original aim was to prove that $K(X)$ is isomorphic to the field of fractions of the co-ordinate ring $A(X)$. And since i know that the field of fractions of $A(X)$ is isomoprhic to the field of fractions of $O_{X,P}$, then it remains me to show that the field of fractions of $O_{X,P}$ is $K(X)$. Maybe for my original aim can i simply consider $$\frac{f}{g}\in K (A(X))\mapsto [(D(g),f/g]\in K(X)$$ where $D(g)$ is the open subset of $X$ in wich $g$ doesn't vanish, and show that this map is an isomoprhism?